# Dropping entire subject if single observation meets criterion in panel data

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have some panel data of the form...

```
id | amount
-----------
1  | 10
1  | 10
1  | 100
2  | 10
2  | 15
2  | 10
3  | 100
```

What I'm looking to do seems like it should be fairly simple, but my experience with Stata is limited and I'm used to programming in languages similar to C/Java. Essentially, I want to drop an entire person (`id`) if any of their individual observations ever exceed a certain amount. So let's say I set this amount to 50, I want to drop all the observations from `id` 1 and `id` 3 such that the data will then only contain observations from `id` 2.

The pseudo-code in Java would be fairly straightforward...

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataset_length; i++) {
   if dataset[i].amount > 50 {
      int drop_id = dataset[i].id;
      for(int j = 0; j < dataset_length; j++) {
         if dataset[j].id == drop_id {
            delete observation
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What would the Stata equivalent of something akin to this be? I'm surely missing something and making it more complicated than it ought to be, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no missings on `amount` this is just

```
bysort id (amount) : drop if amount[_N] > 50
```

If there are missings, then

```
gen ismissing = -missing(amount) 
bysort id (ismissing amount): drop if amount[_N] > 50 & amount[_N] < .
```

would be one kind of check, although it's hard to see how the missings could be interesting or useful.

The machinery here (for one introduction see [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004)) in effect builds in a loop over identifiers, and over the observations for each identifier. Literal translation using models from mainstream programming languages could only result in lengthier and less efficient code.

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly. Thank you for the pdf, too, it definitely is helping me understand STATA better.